# Custom Facebook connect image - Is it Facebook's policy violation?

Tags: facebook

I was going to change Facebook's default login button with my custom image like [Mashable](http://mashable.com/).

I mean like this:

[image]

But [I found a article](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/customising-facebook-connect-s-fb-login-button) which state its against Facebook's policies.

Is it really a violation? If it is how come Mashable using custom image? Can someone answer me?

### Update

This is the exact image I would like to use.

[image]

Facebook mentioned like this in [this page](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php?__adt=5).

> While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify
>   the “f” logo in any other way (such as by changing the design or
>   color). If you are unable to use the correct colour due to technical
>   limitations, you may revert to black and white.

So my sign in with Facebook image violating Facebook policy in anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php.

> This section explains our guidelines regarding the use of Facebook’s
>   logos and other trademarks.

Legally anyone who's modified a Facebook icon and posted it to sites such as `iconfinder.com` has violated Facebook's trademark.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you answer me now? Thanks

Comment: Yes your "f" logo is not 100% exactly the same as the one on their site and violates their trademark. Notice under Usage "Find us on facebook" icon, it is the exact "f" logo placed on top of another graphic. If you found the link in my answer and comment helpful feel free to mark it as the answer. For your graphic I would simply use photoshop to remove the current "f" from that graphic and replace with Facebooks "f" logo